# What is a good technique for finding a simple formula to fit a series of three points?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three points:

- 0: 595
- 90: 1480
- 180: 2440

(The first value is an angle in degrees, the second is the pulse-width in milliseconds that produces that angle on a particular servo-motor.)

As you can see, the line described by these points is not quite linear. (I assume the intermediate points will be roughly on the line though.)

What I would like to do is find a formula that fits the line and gives me the pulse-width for a desired angle. What is a good strategy for doing this? I think I could arrive at something like:

`pw = ((angle * <a multiplier>) + (angle * <a coefficient>)) + 595`

by crude trial and error, but I am sure there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: [Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out the other answers, I discovered two ways of doing this (implemented in Python).

I can create two lists:

```
angles = [-90, 0, 90]
pulse_widths = [595, 1480, 2440]
```

## numpy.polyfit

Then, using [numpy.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit) I can:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.polyfit(angles, pulse_widths, 2)
array([4.62962963e-03, 9.41666667e+00, 5.95000000e+02])
```

And the values it returns can be used to construct the equation I need:

```
pulse_width = 4.62962963e-03 * angle ** 2 + 9.41666667 * angle + 595
```

## Lagrange polynomial

Or I can use a [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

```
pw = (pulse_widths[0] * (angle - angles[1]) * (angle - angles[2])) / ((angles[0] - angles[1]) * (angles[0] - angles[2])) + \
    (pulse_widths[1] * (angle - angles[0]) * (angle - angles[2])) / ((angles[1] - angles[0]) * (angles[1] - angles[2])) + \
    (pulse_widths[2] * (angle - angles[0]) * (angle - angles[1])) / ((angles[2] - angles[0]) * (angles[2] - angles[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that your three points are (essentially) exactly right you can join them by a broken line. That's the [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) in the comment from @PeterForeman . If they are approximate measurements use [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to find the straight line that best fits all three, on average.

I'd be surprised if Python didn't have packages for both.

Answer (score 1):

According to my calculator the linear regression equation is $$y=582.5+10.25x$$

Where $x$ is the angle in degrees and $y$ is puls width

A quadratic regression equation is $$y=0.004629x^2+9.4166x+595$$

Comment: Thanks, the quadratic equation is what I need, because it fits all three points. My question is: how can I find such an equation for a series like that?

Comment: I used my TI 83  stat and quadratic regression