# How can I find a formula to fit a series, of: a value, and a pair of values?

Tags: polynomials

I have [a mechanism](https://brachiograph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can reach a set of x/y co-ordinates. At each x/y point, a certain piece of the mechanism will be at a certain angle.

I would like to record the angle of the piece for a number of different x/y points, and find a formula that fits the data, so that given x/y, I can obtain an angle.

My data series will be in the form:

```
angle, (x, y)
```

[I used polyfit in Python's Numpy library](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3299332/628173) to do [something similar](https://github.com/evildmp/BrachioGraph/blob/f418be144b8f7a1cfe113b291f24a9308435909a/brachiograph.py#L36-L48), but in that case the series was simply of pairs of values.

I am not even sure if what I am trying to do even possible (is it?). If it is possible, what is the name of the technique?

Comment: Could you store data somewhere ?

Comment: From further research, it sounds like what I need to do is a *multiple polynomial regression* - does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, it does (except if you have a physical model that you could tune using nonlinear regression).